# Django how to check for empty value in IntegerField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I am trying to get the set of objects which have no value for the field `units`

The only way I can find to do this on the internet is by using `objects.filter(units__exact = '')` but this does not work for me as my field units is of type int, so I get a type error. How would I check for empy units field?

Comment: Please show us your model field definition - what "empty" means depends on how you've defined the field.

Answer (score 2):

The query **`units__exact = ''`** (lookup [**`exact`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exact)) is for [**`CharField()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) or *similar* fields.

In the case of [**`IntegerField(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#integerfield) the option [**`blank`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank) won't be a valid option. 
So, you could try something [**`isnull`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull) option as,

```
 MyModel.objects.filter(units__isnull=True)
```